Expressing the rational normal curve of degree 3 as the intersection of a quadric and a cubic
Example 2.9 in Hulek's Elementary Algebraic Geometry is as follows: Consider the map $$\begin{align*}\varphi:\mathbb{P}^1 &\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3 \\ (t_0:t_1) &\longmapsto (t_0^3: t_0^2t_1:t_0t_1^2:t_1^3) \end{align*}$$ Then $$C:= \varphi(\mathbb{P}^1) = \left\{(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3) \in \mathbb{P}^3 \ \middle| \ \mathrm{rank}\begin{pmatrix}x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3\end{pmatrix} \leq 1\right\}.$$
Clearly $C = \underbrace{V(x_0x_2-x_1^2)}_{Q_1} \cap \underbrace{V(x_0x_3- x_1x_2)}_{Q_2} \cap \underbrace{V(x_1x_3-x_2^2)}_{Q_3}.$ Hulek claims that $C$ can be written as the intersection of $Q_1$ with a cubic $F$ where
$$F = \{(x_0:x_1:x_2) \in \mathbb{P}^2 \mid x_0x_3^2 - 2x_1x_2x_3+x_2^3=0\},$$ which is nonsense.
Heuristically, why is Hulek's claim true and how can I compute the cubic?

For those of us who don't have Hulek's text close at hand, what is the "nonsense" cubic?

And what is your reason to call it nonsense?

@Sasha It's definition starts with 3 coordinates $(x_0:x_1:x_2)$ and states it is a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ but then uses 4 coordinates.

@AdilRaza That seems more like an obvious typo (with an obvious correction) than genuine "nonsense."

But for reference, the cubic appears to be computed by the formula $x_3Q_2 + x_2Q_3$. By Bezout's theorem, the intersection has degree $2\cdot 3 = 6$ so we conclude that they intersect with multiplicity $2$ (i.e. the quadric and cubic surfaces are tangent along the rational normal curve.

@TabesBridges Why are we allowed to replace $V(Q_2) \cap V(Q_3)$ with $V(x_3Q_2 + x_2Q_2)?$

Remember that any two of the three quadrics intersect in the twisted cubic curve and a secant line. $Q_2\cap Q_3$ is the twisted cubic and the line $x_2=x_3=0.$

Why is this nonsense?
Here is the calculation to make the nonsense clearer (i.e., not nonsense) using Macaulay2:
First, we generate the ring R consisting of $t$'s and $x$'s, and use an elimination order to find the relationship between the $x$'s by eliminating the $t$'s with a Groebner basis.
R = QQ[t_0,t_1,x_0..x_3,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]
I = ideal(x_0-t_0^3,x_1-t_1*t_0^2,x_2-t_1^2*t_0,x_3-t_1^3)
G = flatten entries selectInSubring(1,gens gb I)

The result of this calculation is the following (which matches the minors calculation):
  2                       2
{x  - x x , x x  - x x , x  - x x }
  2    1 3   1 2    0 3   1    0 2

Now, we create a new ring, construct the ideal from these generators ($J$) and construct the ideal with the given generators ($Q_1$ and $F$).
S = QQ[x_0..x_3]
J = sub(ideal G,S)
K = ideal(x_0*x_3^2-2*x_1*x_2*x_3+x_2^3,x_0*x_2-x_1^2)

We can test that $J$ and $K$ are different ideals by checking equality.  However, they cut out the same variety since their radicals are equal.
J == K                       -- false
(radical J) == (radical K)   -- true

As others have said in the comments, the given cubic is $x_3Q_2+x_2Q_3$, which vanishes on the desired curve, but cuts out more.
There is no guarantee that $V(Q_1)$ and $V(x_3Q_2+x_2Q_3)$ cut out the same variety as what was given.  However, by luck, they do!
